# DataFrame only printing last row of XML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, pandas, beautifulsoup, pubmed

Hello I am trying to extract some information from a pubmed XML dataset. Here is the first portion of my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

content = []
with open("phosphiltestfilepmc.xml", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")
    available_contacts = 139
    start_list = 0
    input_tag = bs_content.find_all(attrs={'ref-type': 'corresp'})
```

I am using the find_all function to return all attributes with 'ref-type' = 'corresp' this outputs a 'resultset'

From there I loop through them and grab the parent element as seen below:

```
    l = []
    a = []
    for i in range(start_list, available_contacts):
        d = {}
        b = {}
        try:
            d['firstname'] = input_tag[i].parent('given-names')
        except:
            None
        try:
            d['lastname'] = input_tag[i].parent('surname'))
        except:
            None
        try:
            d['email'] = input_tag[i].parent.parent.parent.parent('corresp')[0]('email')
        except:
            d['email'] = 'j@g.com'
        l.append(d)
    print(l)
```

The result of print(l) is a list of dictionaries(this is a snippet):
`[{'firstname': [<given-names>Inn-Ho</given-names>], 'lastname': [<surname>Tsai</surname>], 'email': [<email>bc201@gate.sinica.edu.tw</email>]}]`

I am trying to get the text from these dictionaries. I do not think get_text() will work on a resultSet.

My solution was to Loop through them again and this time use text.strip() please see the below:

```
        for tag, tag2, tag3, in zip(d['firstname'], d['lastname'], d['email']):
            try:
                b['First Name'] = tag.text.strip()
            except:
                None
            try:
                b['Last Name'] = tag2.text.strip()
            except:
                None
            try:
                b['Email Address'] = tag3.text.strip()
            except:
                None
            a.append(b)
    print(a)
```

The output of 'a' is a list of dictionaries (this is just a snippet): `[{'First Name': 'José María', 'Last Name': 'Gutiérrez', 'Email Address': 'jgutierr@icp.ucr.ac.cr'}]`

The issue arrises when I try to get a DataFrame from 'a'

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(a)
df
```

The output is only the last name in the list of a. Please help.

Here is a snippet of the xml Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pmc-articleset PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD ARTICLE SET 2.0//EN" "https://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pmc/articleset/nlm-articleset-2.0.dtd">
<pmc-articleset><article xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" article-type="research-article">
  <?properties open_access?>
  <front>
    <journal-meta>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="nlm-ta">Braz J Med Biol Res</journal-id>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="iso-abbrev">Braz. J. Med. Biol. Res</journal-id>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id">bjmbr</journal-id>
      <journal-title-group>
        <journal-title>Brazilian Journal of Medical and Biological Research</journal-title>
      </journal-title-group>
      <issn pub-type="ppub">0100-879X</issn>
      <issn pub-type="epub">1414-431X</issn>
      <publisher>
        <publisher-name>Associa&#xE7;&#xE3;o Brasileira de Divulga&#xE7;&#xE3;o Cient&#xED;fica</publisher-name>
      </publisher>
    </journal-meta>
    <article-meta>
      <article-id pub-id-type="pmid">31721904</article-id>
      <article-id pub-id-type="pmc">6853074</article-id>
      <article-id pub-id-type="other">00606</article-id>
      <article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1590/1414-431X20198441</article-id>
      <article-categories>
        <subj-group subj-group-type="heading">
          <subject>Research Article</subject>
        </subj-group>
      </article-categories>
      <title-group>
        <article-title>Behavioral effects of <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a, a proline-rich oligopeptide from <italic>Bothrops jararaca</italic> venom</article-title>
      </title-group>
      <contrib-group>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0003-4646-5682</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Turones</surname>
            <given-names>L.C.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0002-2318-9809</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>da Cruz</surname>
            <given-names>K.R.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0002-4061-8804</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Camargo-Silva</surname>
            <given-names>G.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0003-1799-1106</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Reis-Silva</surname>
            <given-names>L.L.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0002-4997-2658</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Graziani</surname>
            <given-names>D.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <name>
            <surname>Ferreira</surname>
            <given-names>P.M.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0003-2836-5565</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Galdino</surname>
            <given-names>P.M.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff2">2</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0003-0488-5400</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Pedrino</surname>
            <given-names>G.R.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0001-8738-5852</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Santos</surname>
            <given-names>R.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff3">3</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0003-1996-0901</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Costa</surname>
            <given-names>E.A.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff2">2</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0001-5709-9329</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Ianzer</surname>
            <given-names>D.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
          <xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">*</xref>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author">
          <contrib-id contrib-id-type="orcid" authenticated="false">http://orcid.org/0000-0003-4006-8213</contrib-id>
          <name>
            <surname>Xavier</surname>
            <given-names>C.H.</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1">1</xref>
          <xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">*</xref>
        </contrib>
        <aff id="aff1">
<label>1</label>Laborat&#xF3;rio de Neurobiologia de Sistemas, Departamento de Ci&#xEA;ncias Fisiol&#xF3;gicas, Instituto de Ci&#xEA;ncias Biol&#xF3;gicas, Universidade Federal de Goi&#xE1;s, Goi&#xE2;nia, GO, Brasil</aff>
        <aff id="aff2">
<label>2</label>Laborat&#xF3;rio de Farmacologia de Produtos Naturais e Sint&#xE9;ticos, Departamento de Farmacologia, Instituto de Ci&#xEA;ncias Biol&#xF3;gicas, Universidade Federal de Goi&#xE1;s, Goi&#xE2;nia, GO, Brasil</aff>
        <aff id="aff3">
<label>3</label>Departamento de Fisiologia e Biof&#xED;sica, Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais, Belo Horizonte, MG, Brasil</aff>
      </contrib-group>
      <author-notes>
        <corresp id="cor1">Correspondence: C.H. Xavier: &lt;<email>carlosxavier@ufg.br</email>&gt;</corresp>
        <fn fn-type="equal" id="fn1">
          <p>*These authors contributed equally to his work.</p>
        </fn>
      </author-notes>
      <pub-date pub-type="epub">
        <day>07</day>
        <month>11</month>
        <year>2019</year>
      </pub-date>
      <pub-date pub-type="collection">
        <year>2019</year>
      </pub-date>
      <volume>52</volume>
      <issue>11</issue>
      <elocation-id>e8441</elocation-id>
      <history>
        <date date-type="received">
          <day>12</day>
          <month>2</month>
          <year>2019</year>
        </date>
        <date date-type="accepted">
          <day>30</day>
          <month>8</month>
          <year>2019</year>
        </date>
      </history>
      <permissions>
        <license license-type="open-access" xlink:href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
          <license-p>This is an Open Access article distributed under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution License, which permits unrestricted use, distribution, and reproduction in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited.</license-p>
        </license>
      </permissions>
      <abstract>
        <p>The heptapeptide <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a, isolated and identified from <italic>Bothrops jararaca</italic> (<italic>Bj</italic>) venom, produces antihypertensive and other cardiovascular effects that are independent on angiotensin converting enzyme inhibition, possibly relying on cholinergic muscarinic receptors subtype 1 (M<sub>1</sub>R). However, whether <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a acts upon the central nervous system and modifies behavior is yet to be determined. Therefore, the aims of this study were: i) to assess the effects of acute administration of <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a upon behavior; ii) to reveal mechanisms involved in the effects of <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a upon locomotion/exploration, anxiety, and depression-like behaviors. For this purpose, adult male Wistar (WT, wild type) and spontaneous hypertensive rats (SHR) received intraperitoneal injections of vehicle (0.9% NaCl), diazepam (2 mg/kg), imipramine (15 mg/kg), <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a (71, 213 or 426 nmol/kg), pirenzepine (852 nmol/kg), &#x3B1;-methyl-DL-tyrosine (200 mg/kg), or chlorpromazine (2 mg/kg), and underwent elevated plus maze, open field, and forced swimming tests. The heptapeptide promoted anxiolytic and antidepressant-like effects and increased locomotion/exploration. These effects of <italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a seem to be dependent on M<sub>1</sub>R activation and dopaminergic receptors and rely on catecholaminergic pathways.</p>
      </abstract>
      <kwd-group>
        <kwd><italic>Bj</italic>-PRO-7a</kwd>
        <kwd>Snake venom</kwd>
        <kwd>Neuroactive compounds</kwd>
        <kwd>Anxiety</kwd>
        <kwd>Depression</kwd>
        <kwd>Behavior</kwd>
      </kwd-group>
      <counts>
        <fig-count count="9"/>
        <table-count count="0"/>
        <equation-count count="0"/>
        <ref-count count="35"/>
      </counts>
    </article-meta>
  </front>
```

Here is the entire script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

content = []
with open("phosphiltestfilepmc.xml", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")
    available_contacts = 139
    start_list = 0
    #article_meta = bs_content.find_all('article-meta')
    input_tag = bs_content.find_all(attrs={'ref-type': 'corresp'})
    
    # something = []
    # for link in input_tag:
    #     something.append(link.parent.get('given-names'))
    # print(something)
    
    l = []
    a = []
    for i in range(start_list, available_contacts):
        d = {}
        b = {}
        try:
            d['firstname'] = input_tag[i].parent('given-names')
        except:
            None
        try:
            d['lastname'] = input_tag[i].parent('surname')
        except:
            None
        try:
            d['email'] = input_tag[i].parent.parent.parent.parent('corresp')[0]('email')
        except:
            d['email'] = 'j@g.com'
        l.append(d)
    #print(l)
    
        for tag, tag2, tag3, in zip(d['firstname'], d['lastname'], d['email']):
            try:
                b['First Name'] = tag.text.strip()
            except:
                None
            try:
                b['Last Name'] = tag2.text.strip()
            except:
                None
            try:
                b['Email Address'] = tag3.text.strip()
            except:
                None
            a.append(b)
    print(a)
    
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(a)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right: you want to extract names from `<contrib>` tags, where there is `<xref ref-type="corresp">` (`txt` contains the XML snippet from the question):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for contrib in soup.select('contrib:has(> xref[ref-type="corresp"])'):
    cor_id = contrib.select_one('xref[ref-type="corresp"]')['rid']
    email = soup.select_one('corresp#{} email'.format(cor_id))
    email = email.text if email else '-'

    all_data.append({
        'First Name': contrib.select_one('given-names').text,
        'Last Name': contrib.select_one('surname').text,
        'Email Address': email
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  First Name Last Name        Email Address
0         D.    Ianzer  carlosxavier@ufg.br
1       C.H.    Xavier  carlosxavier@ufg.br
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to go about it, is it possible to expand on this? If for example you wanted to loop through each of the <article-meta> tags and grab the name, and email?